# Building WiX on Visual Studio Team Services times out

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix, azure-devops

I have an existing XAML build I am porting over to Visual Studio Team Services build. There is a Solution file that contains two wixproj projects, and this builds with no issues on the current (legacy XAML) Hosted Build Controller (which uses `WiX Toolset v3.7`).

In VS TS, I created a new build process and added a step to **Build solution** using a *Visual Studio Build* step. I have set the Solution path to my sln that contains the two wixproj projects. All the other options are the defaults except the timeout which is set to 10 minutes.

The build step initiates but times out after calling the Light.exe step, as in the log below:

```
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\".
Compile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe -dDebug ...
  Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler version 3.10.3.3007
  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

  {myfile}.wxs
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\Light.exe -out ...
  Windows Installer XML Toolset Linker version 3.10.3.3007
  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

##[error]The task has timed out.
```

The build will run 10 minutes and then throw a timeout error. It usually takes ~1 minute to finish. There is no information in the log about where this may be timing out or why.

I see that VS TS Build uses WiX version 3.10, but WiX version 3.10 works for me locally to build this same sln. I haveve tried all options for `Visual Studio Version` in the build step with same results.

Any ideas what I am missing and why this isn't working?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a post in the [wixtoolset GitHub project](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5486) documenting a bug in `WiX 3.10` about deadlocks occurring with WiX projects if there are any warning or error messages generated during the build.

The workaround is to add the following `MSBuild Arguments` in the build step:

```
/p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true
```

This resolved my issue with the `Light.exe` process timing out.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: I had similar issues with candle.exe timing out in our Team Services build. This argument does to seem to do the trick. Still doesn't explain why the build previously randomly did succeed. Anyway, have my upvote.

Comment: This worked for me but I did get another "error LGHT0217: Error executing ICE action 'ICE01'." that I was able to fix by setting my Azure Agent service to run under an admin user instead of the default networkService.

Comment: This solution still works for the Hosted VS2017 build agent on Azure DevOps pipelines

Answer (score -2):

Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe -dDebug ...
Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler version 3.10.3.3007
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

{myfile}.wxs
Link:
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\Light.exe -out ...
Windows Installer XML Toolset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401880/copying-artifacts-between-builds-in-team-services?rq=1https://vm.tiktok.com/ZTdpeEP2A/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).